# Regex to validate email in tabulator4.8 is not working

Tags: javascript, tabulator

In tabulator 4.8

```
regex:/^[A-Za-z._]{1,}@[A-Za-z]{1,}[.]{1}[A-Za-z.]{2,6}$/
```

If i use this regex in chrome console.
`console.log(/^[A-Za-z._]{1,}@[A-Za-z]{1,}[.]{1}[A-Za-z.]{2,6}$/.test("nayaz@nayaz.com"));`

it returns true which is correct.

if i pass this same rejex to tabulator

```
{ title: "EMAIL_ADDRESS", field: "EMAIL_ADDRESS", hozAlign: "center", width: 148, editor: "input", editable: true, headerFilter: "input", validator: ["required","regex:/^[A-Za-z._]{1,}@[A-Za-z]{1,}[.]{1}[A-Za-z.]{2,6}$/"] },
```

for that same email it throws error, help me in this.

Comment: I don't see anything to do with jQuery Validate plugin here.  Please don't tag spam.  It would also be great if you took the time to properly format the code so others can read it.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass Your Regex as

```
{
    title: "EMAIL_ADDRESS",
    field: "EMAIL_ADDRESS",
    hozAlign: "center",
    width: 148,
    editor: "input",
    editable: true,
    headerFilter: "input",
    validator: [
      "required",
      "regex:^[A-Za-z._]{1,}@[A-Za-z]{1,}[.]{1}[A-Za-z.]{2,6}$"
    ]
}
```